# how to retrieve the data in a sorted order from firebase where the sorting field is the name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
passbuddy-2af92
    Passwords
        pass1
            age: 20
            name: "Shantanu"
        pass2
            age: 42
            name: "Rinku"
        pass3
            age: 51
            name: "Swarup"
```

This is my firebase database. I want to retrieve the data in a sorted order according to the name: i.e.

```
{pass3={name=Swarup, age=51}, pass1={name=Shantanu, age=20}, pass2={name=Rinku, age=42}}
```

or in the reverse order

I've tried these lines of code to achieve the desired task, but they don't seem to work.

```
DatabaseReference databasePasswords = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Passwords");
    databasePasswords.orderByChild("name").startAt("S").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: DATA : " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Thanx for your help in advance guyz...

Comment: What goes wrong when you run the code?

Comment: Nothing goes wrong, i  just dont get the desired result, i.e, i don't get the result in a sorted order...

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. When you use a `ValueEventListener` all the matching nodes will be passed to you in a single `DataSnapshot`. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. Your code will need to handle this list, so that it maintains the order of the matching nodes:

```
DatabaseReference databasePasswords = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Passwords");
databasePasswords.orderByChild("name").startAt("S").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: Key : " + childSnapshot.getKey()+, Name : "+childSnapshot.child("name").getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into sorting, filtering and limiting parts of my Firebase data. This is a good reference page:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data